# How to get the value of a variable in a macro argument

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm, gnu-assembler

Working code in NASM assembly is the following:

```
%macro ISR_NOERRCODE 1
    [GLOBAL isr%1]
    isr%1:
        ...
%endmacro

%assign i 0             ; Initialize the loop Variable

%rep 8
    ISR_NOERRCODE i
    %assign i i+1
%endrep
```

Which expands into 8 code blocks name `isr1`, `isr2`, etc.
But in GAS syntax, the argument given to the macro does not seem to expand. My code is:

```
.macro ISR_NOERRCODE n
    .global isr\n
    isr\n:
        ...
.endm

.set i, 0

.rept
    ISR_NOERRCODE $i
    .set i, $i + 1
.endr
```

Which results in an assembler error:

```
Error: symbol `isr$i' is already defined
```

Because the macro seems to be taking the `$i` argument as a literal string.

Is this even possible in GAS syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is that you'll need to use the [.altmacro](https://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/altmacro.html) directive to enable alternate macro mode. One of the added features is:

> Expression results as strings
>
> You can write %expr to evaluate the expression expr and use the result as a string.

So if we prepend our macro argument with a % it will be evaluated as an expression and turned into a string, which is what we want here. Your code could look like:

```
.altmacro

.macro ISR_NOERRCODE n
    .global isr\n
    isr\n:
         ...

.set i, 0 
.rept 8
    ISR_NOERRCODE %i
    .set i, i + 1 
.endr
```

Conversely you can disable alternate macro mode with [.noaltmacro](https://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/noaltmacro.html) which is the default.